# Usercontrol not found error while viewing form in VS designer

Tags: c#, user-controls

Since some days i get an error of VS designer when opening forms in design view.

> Error: Usercontrol not found.

**Edit**: i checked all references.and did a rebuild. They are all ok. I read in the internet that this may be a bug in vs2010
Can somebody confirm [C# x64 designer user controls not found bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619208/c-x64-designer-user-controls-not-found-bug)?

Comment: I forget my crystal ball at home.

Comment: You have to provide more information. Have you tried rebuilding the solution before opening the control? Have you checked the Designer.cs to see which line (and thus, the control class) VS is unable to locate?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm afraid that this might be the cause, and since we're unable to see the full source code, I think there is nothing more we can do to help you, other than that. But perhaps you can check in the older version of VS if the problem occurs?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall VS2010 ?

Comment: No not yet will try that soon. I actually have problems with my internet connection.i can only go online by mobilephone

Comment: In the meantime, can you try to edit the Designer.cs file of the form and comment out the section with Usercontrol initialization? Then try to open the form, try adding the control again. Then close the form and try to reopen it. Is the error showing up again? If so, I guess it is a bug indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Bug in Visual Studio 2010

Upgraded to 2012 and problem is solved